# DataGridView inside SplitContainer fails to repaint

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView where the first column which can hold an animated gif (an animated loading circle). To make the animation part work I use a Forms.Timer which ticks every 100ms and calls this method

```
    private void timGifAnimation_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 && current >= 0 && current < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count) 
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[current].Cells[0].Value = this.picProcessing.Image;
            this.dataGridView1.InvalidateCell(0, current);
        }
    }
```

This worked like a charmed until I put my DataGridView in a SplitContainer. The cell is no longer repainted with the call to InvalidateCell, the only time when the gif animation works is now when the window is resized or when I'm hovering over a button (hovering repaints it once, moving the mouse away from the button repaints it again). When debugging, the method above is still called, it simply does not repaint the cell.

Comment: Any chance the size of the panel containing the gridview is smaller than the MinSize for that panel (as set on the splitcontainer)?

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating a control or a portion of a control simple marks that area as needing to be repainted.  In order to force a synchronous repaint you should call Update() on the control. Otherwise the invalidated cell will be repainted whenever a paint message next comes along.

```
dataGridView1.Update();
```